# PHP not selecting any value from mysql using prepared sstatement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am working on a php+mysql re-write of the KDE konquest game, with a bunch of added changes.

At the moment I'm rather at the beginning, with the registration working (Checked, users are being created in the database, cookies are set, etc). However, after the user is created, the following code isn't outputting the username:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["user_cookie"])){
    $sql_update_user_time = 'Select user_name from users WHERE user_cookie=?';
    $stmt=mysqli_prepare($mysqli,$sql_update_user_time);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"i",$_COOKIE["user_cookie"]);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$user_name);
    var_dump("execute:".mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)." ");
    var_dump("fetch:".mysqli_stmt_fetch()." ");
    echo "<h1>Greetings $user_name! The empire's fleet awaits your command. </h1>";
}
```

Instead, here is the output (after logging in):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   index of php-on-quest.
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  bool(true)
NULL
<h1>Greetings ! The empire's fleet awaits your command. </h1> </body>
</html>
```

Having looked at the documentation, fetch returning NULL means that there was no error, but no data was extracted from the database.

I have checked, if I manually run the expected sql query, it returns what is expected, that is to say, exactly one username.

Minimal Database:

```
table users:
user_id:int(11) primary key
user_name: char(11)
user_cookie:int(11) unique
```

Comment: This is the part where you need to step through your code, and do basic debugging steps: `var_dump($_COOKIE)`. What is `user_cookie` set to? Does `user_cookie` with that number exist in your database? `var_dump(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))`, is it being executed successfully?

Comment: are these cusom functions? `mysqli_stmt_execute()` is not in the docs, but `mysqli_execute()` is

Comment: Instead of using `echo` you should do a `var_dump()` of the result of `mysqli_stmt_fetch()`. Most likely it is `null` which means that no rows were found. If it returns `false` you need to check for errors. Which is always a good idea of course.

Comment: @FrankerZ I have checked the cookie using firefox's tools, it is set, execute returns 1, which i *assume* is a truthy value. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Comment: @delboy1978uk http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Comment: [mysqli_stmt_fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) needs the $stmt as param

Comment: thats bizarre, I search for it and get `mysqli_stmt_execute doesn't exist. Closest matches: `

Comment: @jeroen I assume TRUE would be '1', FALSE would be '0' and NULL would be ''. This is what I base the paragraph before last on.

Comment: @delboy1978uk yes, the search in php.net is....well... more a luck thing.

Comment: youre not kidding! I always have issues finding the correct date time formats page, it appears there are 3 and have different formats :-|

Comment: @MarkGardner No, when you try `echo false;` you will not see anything: https://3v4l.org/DlR10

Comment: @jeroen Ah. checking...

Comment: Avoid using `echo` for debugging variables. `var_dump()` will not only echo out what's inside the variable, but tell you the type and length. It's usually the preferred method. Also, you should make sure to enable [error reporting](//php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` which would tell you exactly what is wrong in this case.

Comment: @jeroen edited, with results.

Comment: @Jeff Why not make that an answer? It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One major problem is that you missed to pass `$stmt` to [mysqli_stmt_fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php). This would have thrown an Error (or at least a Warning) which would have told you what the problem is. Please see FrankerZs comment about enabling [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)!

Conclusio:
this line

```
var_dump("fetch:".mysqli_stmt_fetch()." ");
```

should be

```
var_dump("fetch:".mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)." ");
```